# Simple applications of Lie algebra in group theory

Tags: group-theory, lie-algebras, applications

In his book Lie Algebra, Jacobson gives a motivation for Lie algebra as a tool used in a difficult problem in group theory - Burnside's problem.

I was wondering if there is any *simple/elementary* application of Lie algebra in group theory which can be illustrated in class in the beginnning/introduction while teaching the course on Lie algebra.

Comment: For instance, to show that every centerless Lie group is linear (via the adjoint representation).

Comment: If a group has a descending central series G_0 < G_1 · · · we can construct a graded Lie ring from it. This is useful in studying free groups and nilpotent groups, but I don't know if you would consider it elementary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are more elementary questions than the famous Burnside problems, namely some problems concerning the solvability class of $p$-groups. They have a proof using basic Lie algebra theory. For example, we have the following question by Burnside:

*Question (Burnside 1913):* What is the smallest order of a group with prime power order and derived length $k$ ?

Let us denote this order by $p^{\beta_p(k)}$. One can show the following result:

*Proposition:* For $k\ge 4$ and all primes $p$ we have 
$$
\beta_p(k)\ge 2^{k-1}+2k−4.
$$
A proof only using elementary Lie algebra theory was given by L. A. Bokut in $1971$.
For references on similar problems see [here](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_48_derived_lie.pdf).

Edit: For an introductory class in Lie algebras, an easier example is perhaps to
show that under certain assumptions one may put all elements of a matrix group simultaneously into triangular form. This can be proved by Lie's Theorem for Lie algebras, which is a basic result in any class on Lie algebras.

Answer (score 1):

Geometric control theory.  If you would like a specific example, see [the Reeds-Schepp car](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/SHORTEST-PATHS-FOR-THE-REEDS-SHEPP-CAR%3A-A-WORKED-OF-Sussmann-Tang/dd9dcf2c4a2636c03a8a0b589421ef1e4ece6cfc).

The groups in control theory are the 1-parameter groups of diffeomorphisms induced by the vector fields that are the controls.